# how to show/hide SVG elements in javascript or angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, svg

I have created flowchart digram using SVG in angularjs and javscript.

I am creating `Rectangle`, `line`, `text` dynamically.

and digrame look like this [image]

Now i want when i click any of the compute, control or storage rectangle then it's child element should be hide/show(toggle) . (Bydefault it should be hide)

I have created a function like this

```
 $scope.addText = function (x, y, text, textcolor, id) {
                    var segmentText = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
                    segmentText.setAttribute('x', x);
                    segmentText.setAttribute('y', y);
                    segmentText.textContent = text;
                    segmentText.setAttribute('fill', textcolor);
                    segmentText.setAttribute('font-weight', 'bold');
                    segmentText.setAttribute('id', id);
                    svg.appendChild(segmentText);
                };


                $scope.addLine = function (id, x1, y1, x2, y2, color) {
                    var newLine = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
                    newLine.setAttribute('id', id);
                    newLine.setAttribute('x1', x1);
                    newLine.setAttribute('y1', y1);
                    newLine.setAttribute('x2', x2);
                    newLine.setAttribute('y2', y2);
                    newLine.setAttribute('style', color);
                    svg.appendChild(newLine);
                };

                $scope.addRect = function (x, y, rx, ry, width, height, rectcolors, id, attr) {
                    $scope.hidechild = false;
                    var rectangle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');
                    rectangle.setAttribute('x', x);
                    rectangle.setAttribute('y', y);
                    rectangle.setAttribute('rx', rx);
                    rectangle.setAttribute('ry', ry);
                    rectangle.setAttribute('id', id);
                    rectangle.setAttribute('class', 'hiderect');
                    rectangle.setAttribute('width', width);
                    rectangle.setAttribute('height', height);
                    rectangle.setAttribute('style', rectcolors);
                   }
```

example :- [example](https://jsfiddle.net/rushijogle/Lm5rtc4j/1/)

thanx in advance

Comment: You can simply use document.getElementById('id_1').style.display = 'none' to hide your element

Comment: I would consider using D3, it will make your life a lot easier! Take a look at the examples: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery